# How to extract program sub-objects from SE80?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

Does anyone know how to **extract program list objects from package**. 
Classes,fileds,screend ? or in which the tables can I find this information.
Like in the picture below...
is there any way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single class or FM to fulfill your requirement, but you can combine several approaches for implementing the requirement:

1. **RS_PROGRAM_INDEX** FM, where you put program name into `PG_NAME` parameter

It will list all types and data declarations, along with the **subroutines**!

2. **RS_GET_ALL_INCLUDES** FM will list all program includes if existent
3. **REPOSITORY_ENVIRONMENT_RFC** remote-enabled FM which lists all types, data declarations and all function and interface calls in the report codebase. It should be called like:

   ```
   OBJ_TYPE -> PROG
   OBJECT_NAME -> <report>
   ```

If all this is not suffcicient, you can use ABAP [`READ REPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapread_report.htm) statement which fetches report full source code into internal table, and then you can analyze it with Regex or any other tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check in transaction se16 or se16n the tables tadir and tfdir out. With the correct selection you will find your reports and classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this installing SAPLink and download what do you want.

SAPLink: https://app.assembla.com/spaces/saplink/wiki